# URLRewrite link duplication

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a problem with URLRewriting where the rule is overlapping and causing a duplicate URL.

The url in question I **dont** want to overlap is : http://example.com/tracker/add

unfortunately I have a URLRewrite rule which is causing this issue to occur because it's using "add" as part of the original tracker url rewrite (if that makes sense)

The rule is `RewriteRule    ^tracker/([0-9a-zA-Z-\ ]+)/?$    tracker/index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]`

I'm really unsure how I can exclude the http://example.com/tracker/add link from this URLRewrite rule.

My file directory is similar to:

public_html
  tracker
    * index.php?id=test
    add
      * index.php